# Logo On the Appropriate Place Like the Sample

Tags: article, logos

I want to place a logo like this in my article class, like the below sample

[image: the sample of what I want]

[image: the logo to be used]

**This is what I have tried**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz}
\begin{document}
    %%% remove comment delimiter ('%') and select language if required
    %\selectlanguage{spanish} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-53.5pt,xshift=43pt]%
        at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[height=5mm]{futa_logo.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \noindent \textbf{THE FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF LATEX, TEXT}
    
    %\noindent \textbf{\includegraphics*[width=0.78in, height=0.63in, keepaspectratio=false]{image1}
        %       SCHOOL OF POSTGRADUATE STUDIES}
    
    \noindent \textbf{}
    
    \noindent \textbf{FORM:  SPGS/ARTT-AE}
    
    \noindent \textbf{}
    
    \noindent \textbf{APPLICATION FOR REGISTRATION OF THESIS TITLE}
    
    \noindent \textbf{AND APPOINTMENT OF EXAMINERS}
    
    \noindent \textbf{}
    
    \noindent \textbf{SECTION ``A''}
    
    \noindent \textbf{}
    
    \noindent \textbf{(TO BE COMPLETED BY THE CANDIDATE)}
    
    \noindent \textbf{}
    
    \noindent \textbf{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that transparency in PNGs will be displayed black.

Comment: I can see, I only use this as an illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the **minipage environment**, so it is very simple to control the size of the image along with the text.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

%%% remove comment delimiter ('%') and select language if required
%\selectlanguage{spanish} 
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 3cm]{futa_logo.png}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{THE FEDERAL UNIVERSITY OF LATEX, TEXT}
    
        \vspace{0.5cm}
    \textbf{SCHOOL OF POSTGRADUATE STUDIES}
    
        \vspace{0.5cm}
    \textbf{FORM:  SPGS/ARTT-AE}
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{}

    \textbf{APPLICATION FOR REGISTRATION OF THESIS TITLE}
    
    \textbf{AND APPOINTMENT OF EXAMINERS}
    
    \textbf{}
    
    \textbf{SECTION ``A''}
    
    \textbf{}
    
    \textbf{(TO BE COMPLETED BY THE CANDIDATE)}
    
    \textbf{}
    
    \textbf{}
\end{center}





\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

> Note that this method is not the best, nor the most optimized, but it works the way you want it to. If you want something more sophisticated, I can make another answer for that.

Comment: Please show your complete code, including the preamble; it is not running here.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to say that I added the float package